# How to write to csv a dataframe with config line before headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm using a pyhton script to manage different logfiles from an acquisition system, boards ecc.
I'm building a big dataframe which is the merge of other dfs and at the end i'm putting it to a csv file, below last line:

```
dF_COMP.to_csv(path1 + nomefile, sep=';', decimal= ',' , columns=columns)
```

I want to add in the first line of the csv a row with configuration parameters.

I can build the csv with the dataframe, then open it again and then add the line but I think is not the best idea as I expect to build even big files...
Any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can build the csv with the dataframe, then open it again and then add the line but I think is not the best idea as I expect to build even big files...

Do the opposite:

```
with open(path1 + nomefile, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(f'# Config blah blah\n')  # note the '#' as comment character
    df.to_csv(csvfile, sep=';', decimal= ',', columns=columns)
```

To read the file again with `pd.read_csv`:

```
pd.read_csv(path1 + nomefile, comment='#')  # to skip lines begin with '#'

# OR

pd.read_csv(path1 + nomefile, skiprows=1)  # to skip the first line
```

Comment: Soooo easy, I was thinking only to dificult solutions...

Comment: the only problem is that now the dataframe has an empty line every full line... any idea?

Comment: dF_COMP.to_csv(csvfile, sep=';', decimal= ',', columns=columns,lineterminator= '\n') adding line terminator avoids blank lines in the dataframe

Comment: It's curious. Check if there is no trailing \n in your last column.